# Increase an array with dynamic name

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have an array like this:

```
var music = ['Youtube','MP3s','Soundcloud','Streaming']
```

In the first step i create an array for each item

```
for (var p = 0; p < music.length; p++) {  
  window[music[p]] = [0,0,0,0,0,0];
}
```

There is als a small function which increases the item-count in an array at a specific index.

```
function incArray(array, index){
    array[index]++;
}
```

Now i want to increase the item-count in each array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < music.length; i++) {  
  incArray(music[i], 1);
}
```

But this leaves the arrays unchanged (see fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/pLpz2yv2/).
What kind of mistake do i have?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3):

in your second loop where you call incArray, you have a typo:

it should be:

```
incArray(window[music[i]], 1);
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/pLpz2yv2/4/)